# WebService Get Json

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a problem,
I want to make a web service to get Json.

My json is this :

```
[{"id":"test","prix":"0,76"},{"id":"test2","prix":"0,76"},{"id":"BODOUR","prix":"0,76"}]
```

And my code :

```
    @GetMapping(value="/setup/tarif/getTarifElectricity")
public JSONArray getTarifGrid() throws IOException, SAXException {

    String filePath = Common.filePathData("setup.tarif", "tarif.txt");
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
    String tarifGrid = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(tarifGrid);
    System.out.println(jsonArr.toString());
    return jsonArr;
}
```

But when i want to test my webservice my result is that :

```
{"empty": false}
```

localhost:8080/setup/tarif/getTarifElectricity on chrome display {"empty":false} and not my JsonArray

My SYSOUT return me :

```
[{"prix":"0,76","id":"test"},{"prix":"0,76","id":"test2"},{"prix":"0,76","id":"BODOUR"}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Your SYSOUT looks fine. Unclear what "my navigator" means

Comment: http://localhost:8080/setup/tarif/getTarifElectricity on chrome display {"empty":false} and not my JsonArray

Comment: Did you recompile your code and restart the web server?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried to return a String from the method? I mean something like:

```
return jsonArr.toString();
```

In my opinion the reason is that the JSONArray Object only contains the information wether it is empty or not. So Jackson maps the JSON representation of this object with only this information. But if you want to get all data you need to use `jsonArr.toString();`

Comment: The return type of the method is not a string

Comment: Try to set the return type of the method to a string.